# compiler error in hibernate 5.0.1

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning hibernate, I have added all the required jars, but still am getting a compiler error saying

> Configuration.configure cannot be resolved to a type.

My jar list:
[image]

Anyone have idea how to resolve this?

```
package org.ramya.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.ramya.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {


    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("First user");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the **parentheses ()** when instantiating the `Configuration` object.

It should be:

```
new Configuration().configure()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use This,

```
 SessionFactory sf;
            ServiceRegistry sr;
            Configuration cfg=new Configuration().configure();
            sr=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).build();
            sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory(sr);
```

Instead of ,

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Since "buildSessionFactory()" has been deprecated over hibernate 3.5

And try to use latest version of hibernate as much as possible.

Please check this link for Details:-
[Deprecated Buildsessionfactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks Srikanth and Aniket. ya, i understand buildsessionfactory is deprecated ...do you know any specific online tutorials for hibernate 5?

Comment: Sorry i don't know any tutorial for hibernate 5 but i would recommend you to watch this:-  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yv2xctJxE-w&list=PL4AFF701184976B25  which is of hibernate 3.5  could make you understand basic concepts of hibernate.

Comment: Thank you Srikanth, will check that out.